# Submitting dynamic forms on another website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize

I'm trying to submit input to the form, and parse the results in a RoR app. I've tried using mechanize, but it has some trouble with the way the page dynamically updates the results. It doesn't help that most fields are hidden.

Is there anyway to get mechanize to do what I'm looking for, or are there any alternatives to mechanize which I can use?

Comment: Unless you show some code, you are almost guaranteed to be closed as not a real question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So whenever I want to do something like this, I go with the gem selenium-webdriver. It spawns a real browser (supports all major brands) and lets you control it with ruby code. You can do almost everything a real user could do. In addition, you have access to the (rendered) dom, so javascript generated content is not a problem.

Performance is much slower than with pure library clients, so its not a good fit for use in a web request cycle.

http://rubygems.org/gems/selenium-webdriver